# Returned JSON from fetch requests differs in test and dev

Tags: reactjs, redux, karma-runner, fetch, enzyme

I hope my question title is comprehensible enough. I could't really think of a better way to phrase it and the character count restrictions busted my balls.

The problem I'm having happens in a project I'm working on that uses React, Redux and packages like react-router-redux and redux-auth-wrapper.

For testing I'm using Karma test runner with Enzyme, Sinon and Chai. Within the tests I'm using fetchMock to mock any requests to the API I'm using. I bundle everything using Webpack.

The issue I'm facing is that the code I wrote (modified [this](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) starter template rather rigorously) works, but the tests I wrote for them don't produce correct results. The bit that's acting weird is when I dispatch an action to fetch a token from our authentication API.

The Redux action I'm dispatching is the following one:

```js
export function fetchToken(data) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestTokenCreate(data))

    // Let's fetch this user a token, shall we?
    var headers = new Headers()
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json")
    headers.append("Accept", "application/json")

    let requestParams = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'default',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        subdomain: data.subdomain,
        login: data.username,
        password: data.password
      })
    }
    data = {
      subdomain: data.subdomain,
      username: data.username
    }
    var serverUrl = (__DEV__ || __TEST__) ? "http://subdomain.easyposonline.dev:3000/api/v1" : "https://subdomain.easyposonline.nl/api/v1"
    serverUrl = serverUrl.replace("subdomain", data.subdomain)
    return fetch(serverUrl + "/auth_tokens/create", requestParams)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        return dispatch(receiveTokenCreate(json, data))
      }
    )
  }
}
```

The bit relevant to my question is this:

```js
return fetch(serverUrl + "/auth_tokens/create", requestParams)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
      return dispatch(receiveTokenCreate(json, data))
  }
)
```

When I dispatch this action in my development code, it works just fine! This returns the following response:

```js
{success: true, token: "a3PC6y6nx1f63o2b13YWz7LYUHdidYui"}
```

When the action is dispatched from the test in question, though, I get back the following response:

```js
{type: 'RECEIVE_USER_TOKEN_CREATE', json: Object{success: true, token: 'qicXyn6BhYhyoBuA_SFoZtTDN'}, payload: Object{subdomain: 'test-teun', username: 'teun@easypos.nl', token: 'qicXyn6BhYhyoBuA_SFoZtTDN'}}
```

So instead of returning the proper response, the code returns what seems to be an entire Redux action. This leads to my test failing because I end up with a bit of a recursion in the code I'm testing:

```js
{type: 'RECEIVE_USER_TOKEN_CREATE', response: Object{type: 'RECEIVE_USER_TOKEN_CREATE', json: Object{success: ..., token: ...}, payload: Object{subdomain: ..., username: ..., token: ...}}, payload: Object{subdomain: 'test-teun', username: 'teun@easypos.nl'}}
```

I'm at a loss here. Probably I'm overlooking something astonishingly simple, but been looking at this for a few hours now and starting to lose my frickin' mind!

The test file I wrote is the following, maybe I'm setting up a test the wrong way:

```js
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
// import nock from 'nock'
import 'isomorphic-fetch'
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock'

import SignInView from 'routes/SignIn'
import * as constants from 'constants'
import { fetchToken, destroyToken } from 'actions/user'
import _ from 'underscore'

describe('(Route) SignIn', () => {
  let _route = SignInView({})

  // Auth token request
  const authTokenCreateSuccessfulRequest = {
    subdomain: 'test-teun',
    username: 'teun@easypos.nl',
    password: 'psv4teun'
  }
  const authTokenCreateFailedRequest = {
    subdomain: 'test-teun',
    username: 'teun@easypos.nl',
    password: 'teun4psv'
  }
  const authTokenCreateSuccessfulResponse = {
    type: constants.RECEIVE_USER_TOKEN_CREATE,
    json: {
      success: true,
      token: 'qicXyn6BhYhyoBuA_SFoZtTDN'
    },
    payload: {
      subdomain: 'test-teun',
      username: 'teun@easypos.nl',
      token: 'qicXyn6BhYhyoBuA_SFoZtTDN'
    }
  }
  const authTokenCreateFailedResponse = {
    type: constants.RECEIVE_USER_TOKEN_CREATE,
    json: {
      success: false,
      reason: "Ongeldige gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord!"
    },
    payload: {
      subdomain: 'test-teun',
      username: 'teun@easypos.nl'
    }
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchMock.mock('http://test-teun.easyposonline.dev:3000/api/v1/auth_tokens/create', authTokenCreateSuccessfulResponse)
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    fetchMock.restore()
  })

  it('Should return a route configuration object', () => {
    expect(typeof _route).to.equal('object')
  })

  it('Should define a route component', () => {
    expect(_route.path).to.equal('sign_in')
  })

  const middlewares = [ thunk ]
  const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

  it('Should trigger RECEIVE_USER_TOKEN_CREATE action containing a token on a successful login attempt', () => {
    //fetchMock.mock('http://test-teun.easyposonline.dev:3000/api/v1/auth_tokens/create', authTokenCreateSuccessfulResponse)
    const expectedActions = [
      {
        type: constants.REQUEST_USER_TOKEN_CREATE,
        payload: authTokenCreateSuccessfulRequest
      },
      authTokenCreateSuccessfulResponse
    ]
    const store = mockStore({ user: { isFetching: false } })

    return store.dispatch(fetchToken(authTokenCreateSuccessfulRequest))
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(store.getActions()[1])
        // console.log(expectedActions[1])
        expect(_.isEqual(store.getActions(), expectedActions)).to.equal(true)
      })
  })
})
```

Another thing I might note is that I had this test working yesterday but I modified the structure of my Redux state since then and seem to have broken something along the way... :( Looking back in my Git history did not help me with this annoying thing.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction here, it'd really help me and my peace of mind. Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Sigh... I discovered my dumb error. `fetchMock.mock('http://test-teun.easyposonline.dev:3000/api/v1/auth_tokens/create', authTokenCreateSuccessfulResponse)` should be `fetchMock.mock('http://test-teun.easyposonline.dev:3000/api/v1/auth_tokens/create', authTokenCreateSuccessfulResponse.payload)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh... I discovered my dumb error.
`fetchMock.mock('http://test-teun.easyposonline.dev:3000/api/‌​v1/auth_tokens/creat‌​e', authTokenCreateSuccessfulResponse)`
should be
`fetchMock.mock('http://test-teun.easyposonline.dev:3000/api/‌​v1/auth_tokens/creat‌​e', authTokenCreateSuccessfulResponse.payload)`